# form submit button doesn't work after onsubmit return false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

before submit i'm checking 2 fields if one of two fields is checked i return true else false. the problem is that if false is return , ido check one of two checkboxes but  the submit button doesn't seem to work(i do console.log()) on click it shows customvalidity message

gif that shows the problem [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nr3o.gif)

here is code :

```
function validateForm() {
  var checkcapelli = $('#TaglioCapelli').is(':checked'); 
  var checkcolore = $('#checkcolore').is(':checked');
  console.log(checkcapelli);
  console.log(checkcolore); 
  console.log("hello");

  if (checkcapelli || checkcolore){
    return true;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('TaglioCapelli').setCustomValidity("Selezionare almeno una opzione");
    return false;   
  }
}
```

form (i removed some fields): I do check two checkboxes:

```
<form id="userForm" action="php/userForm.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">         




                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"   name ="TaglioCapelli" id="TaglioCapelli" >
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="TaglioCapelli">
                       Taglio Capelli
                      </label> 
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly value ="30" name ="tempTaglioCapelli" id="tempTaglioCapelli" >
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="tempTaglioCapelli">
                        Tempo in minuti
                       </label> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name ="checkcolore" id="checkcolore" >
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkcolore">
                        Colore Capelli
                      </label>
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="number" readonly name ="tempcheckcolore" value ="40" id="tempcheckcolore" >
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="tempcheckcolore">
                        Tempo in minuti
                       </label> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="noteUser">Note</label>
                      <input type="text" name ="noteUser"  class="form-control" id="noteUser" placeholder="Opzionale">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="finalTime">Tempo finale stimato</label>
                      <input type="text" name ="finalTime"  class="form-control" readonly id="finalTime" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 tratdati">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" required name ="CheckDati" id="CheckDati" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="CheckDati">
                      Autorizzo il trattamento dei dati
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="submit" id="sendUserForm"  class="btn btn-primary">Prenota</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Isn't that what you want? if validation (onsubmit) returns false (fails validation) you don't want the form to submit, but if it returns true, then you want to submit.  Can you please clarify your question.

Comment: yes but the problem is that if return false , after i check the checkbox and click submit but nothing happens and it shows setCustomValidity message

Comment: @user6269972 added also gif that shows the problem

Answer (score 0):

Because when you first submit the form, it puts the form in an 'invalid' state.  The form will not submit until the fields are changed to put the form in a valid state.

Two options:

```
$('input[name="myinput"]').on("blur", () => {
    // Do your checks and setCustomValidity depending on if is valid or not
});
```

Or you can change your submit button to a

```
type="button" onclick="submitForm()"
function submitForm() {
...do my validation checks
call form.submit() if validation passes. 
}
```

Comment: ok with 2 method it seem to work but the setCustomValidity doesn't appear or it doesn't work any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the check box html from

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name ="TaglioCapelli" id="TaglioCapelli" >
```

to

```
 <input onClick="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name ="TaglioCapelli" id="TaglioCapelli" >
```

here on click we are nullifying the custom validation added. 
Note: in this case even you tried to check other checkbox and try to submit, it will still not submit the form as per the validation logic you have set.